# Antenna trace 135 degree bending

Tags: pcb, trace, pcb-antenna, microstrip

I designing PCB for SIM7600CE with space constraint.Here, I placing filter matching and the antenna section through 135 degree angle traces (GREEN MARKING).Is it Okay?Can I have any PCB guidelines?
GSM  frequency:EGSM 900MHz/DCS1800MHz
GNSS frequency: 1575.42±1.023MHz
[image]

Comment: What frequency is this operating at? It could be beneficial to add the frequency and other parameters of the system to your question, so people don't have to go look it up.

Comment: How do you get this to 135°? Is a straight line a 180° angle?